# Finding "$a$" value in a quadratic equation given axis of symmetry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Given axis of symmetry$\ x=1$ for the parabola $\ y = ax^2 + 4x - 2$. What is the value of $ a$?

I am just curious what is proper method of solving this. This is how I did it:
$$
y = ax^2 + 4x - 2 
$$
$$
0 =  a(1)^2 + 4(1) - 2
$$$$0 = a + 2
$$$$a = -2$$

Is this the correct way of solving it? Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are claiming that the quadratic curve passes through $(1,0)$ without justification.

Guide:

Notice that the extreme point occur at axis of symmetry for a quadratic function. Hence if you differentiate the quadratic function and equate it to zero, $x=1$ is a solution.

Alternatively, you can also obtain the axis of symmetry by using completing the square technique.

Answer (score 1):

The axis of symmetry of a parabola, is essentially  the unique point $p$ such that $f(p+a) = f(p-a)$ for all $a \geq 0$, since this is what symmetry means about that point. Here we are given $p = 1$.

Now all we need to do, is substitute this in : $$f(1+x) = f(1-x) \implies a(1+x)^2 + 4(1+x) - 2 = a(1-x)^2 + 4(1-x) - 2$$

Now, simplify the above to get:
$$
a(1+x)^2 =a(1-x)^2 - 8x \implies 4ax = -8x 
$$

Since this is true for all $x \geq 0$, you can  conclude that $4a = -8$ and hence $a = -2$.

Comment: $a = -2$, not $2$.

Comment: Yes, it is a small error. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a form in which to write quadratic equations called the turning point form, or completing the square.
$$ y=a(x-h)^2+k $$
where $a$ is the horizontal dilation, $(h,k$) is the turning point. This implies the axis of symmetry is at $x = h$.

For your above example, you would solve the question like this:

\begin{align}
y & = ax^2 + 4x - 2 \\
& = a(x^2+\frac{4}{a}x - \frac {2}{a}) \\
& = a[(x+\frac{2}{a})^2-\frac{4}{a^2}-\frac{2}{a}] \\
& = a[(x+\frac{2}{a})^2-\frac{4-2a}{a^2}] \\
& = a(x+\frac{2}{a})^2-\frac{4-2a}{a} \\
\end{align}

We know axis of symmetry is at $x=1$, and we have previously discussed that $h$ is the axis of symmetry of the turning point form. Therefore it is correct to say $h=-\frac{2}{a}$.

\begin{align}
h &= -\frac {2}{a}\\
\therefore a &= -2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do it! For any parabola, the axis of symmetry is 
$$
x = \frac{-b}{2a}
$$
So for parabola $ ax^2 + 4x - 2,$ $$
1 = \frac{-4}{2a} \Longrightarrow
2a = -4 
$$ Hence,
$$
a = -2
$$